# How to find the Servers response in a C# ClientBase with BasicHTTPBinding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl, basichttpbinding

I am using C# with Visual Studio. I have imported a WSDL file into my project, so that VS automatically created a class for me to use the appropriate services.

Now I got an error from the server and for debugging purposes I would like to see the RAW response of the server. It looks that this is quite complicated to obtain.

Please take a look at the screenshot below:

[image]

I've got only the "base.channel" object. But also after a long time of digging into all the attributes and sub-objects, I'm still not able to find the actual servers response.

The code on line 6776 is the first and only one where I can stop. So there is no possibility to look into some objects earlier.

I'm quite new to Server Client based applications with C# and WSDL. I really hope, that the mechanism, how the requests work, are always the same, so that someone could give me a hint how I can retrieve the servers raw response.

Since it is HTTPS, wireshark is no option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I used Fiddler which is able to decrypt also SSL traffic!